# In Azure Java Functions unable to read host.json values in test/production environment

Tags: java, function, azure

I am trying to implement once simple Azure Java Function where host.json entries changes w.r.t each slots ( environment ) . I need to read those value in my java class.
Locally I am able to read it using System.getEnv which may be referring local-settings.json, however when deployed in azure site its not working.Please suggust

Comment: Have you add these settings in your Azure function application  settings : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

The host.json metadata file contains global configuration options that affect all functions for a function app.

For more details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

For your requirement, you need to add settings in your function application settings:

[image]

And then add environment settings here:

[image]

---

Update

If you develop with VS Code, you can add Azure Function extension, and then you can upload all you local settings:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jack, thanks for the clarification.May I know if there is any option I can upload application settings without manually adding ( maven command ) . I will like to load couple of properties while deployment specific to environments.

Comment: If you uses VS Code to develop, then you can use command palette: F1 -> Upload Local Settings.

Comment: I am aware maven plugin option .. <appSettings>  false  Specifies the application settings for your Azure Functions, which are defined in name-value pairs like following example:
<property>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <value>xxxx</value>
</property> , problem with this is I need to change the pom.xml every time w.r.t environment.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the first issue resolution.I guess I will explore more to see better options.